# JavaScript фильтрация HTML таблицы по нескольким значениям

Tags: javascript, html5

Имеется HTML таблица:

```html
<head>
    <title>Список комментариев</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="1" >
        <caption>Менеджер задач</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Фильтры:</th>
                <th><select id = 'creator_filter' class = 'sel' ><option></option>
                        {% for item in users %}
                            <option>{{ item }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                </select></th>
                <th><select id = 'performer_filter' onchange="filter(this, 'MyTable')"><option></option>
                        {% for item in users %}
                            <option>{{ item }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                </select></th>
                <th><input name="filt" onkeyup="filter(this, 'MyTable')"  type="text" /></th>
                <th>Задача завершена</th>
                <th>Операции</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Задача</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Заявитель</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Исполнитель</th>
                <th>Задача создана</th>
                <th>Задача завершена</th>
                <th>Операции</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id = "MyTable">
            {% for cell in table %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{cell.task}}</td>
                    <td>{{cell.creator}}</td>
                    <td>{{cell.performer}}</td>
                    <td>{{cell.created}}</td>
                    {% if not cell.solved %}
                        <td><div id='td{{ cell.id }}'></div></td>
                        <td><button id="bt{{ cell.id }}" class = login_button  type="submit" onclick="return commit_table({{ cell.id }});">Завершить задачу</button></td>
                    {% else %}
                        <td>{{cell.solved}}</td>
                    {% endif %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
                <tr id = 'addRow'>
                    <td><input type="text" id="edit_task" name="edit_task" size="30" maxlength="100"/></td>
                    <td><div id = "creator">{{ request.user.username }}</div></td>
                    <td><select id = 'edit_selection' name="edit_selection"><option></option>
                        {% for item in users %}
                            <option>{{ item }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <button class = login_button  type="submit" onclick="return validateTable();">Добавить задачу</button>
                    </td>

                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Данную таблицу необходимо одновременно фильтровать по нескольким столбцам. Путем гугления нашел рабочий вариант для одного столбца:

```js
function filter (phrase, _id){
    var words = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    var table = document.getElementById(_id);
    for (var r = 0; r < table.rows.length-1; r++){
        var cellsV = table.rows[r].cells[2].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,"");
        console.log(cellsV);
        var displayStyle = 'none';
        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (cellsV.toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i])>=0)
            displayStyle = '';
        else {
            displayStyle = 'none';
            break;
        }
        }
    table.rows[r].style.display = displayStyle;
    }
}
```

В моем случае он фильтрует таблицу по третьему столбцу. Однако, если подобный фильтр сделать для второго столбца, то при его фильтрации, сбросится фильтр третьего.

Перерыл весь Интернет - не нашел простого и локаничного примера, можно наверное сделать одновременную фильтрацию через глобальные переменные, чтоб сохранить фильтры, но вроде бы это дурная практика.

Подскажите, как правильно в моем случае произвести фильтрацию данной HTML таблицы по нескольким столбцам одновременно (например по второму и третьему) средствами JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте это: третьим параметром передавайте номер столбца, а четвертым, если фильтр должен учитывать предыдущие фильтры не передавайте ничего, а если не должен то true.

```
function filter(phrase, _id, cellNumber, resetFilter) {
   var words = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
   var table = document.getElementById(_id);
   for (var r = 0; r < table.rows.length - 1; r++) {
      if (!resetFilter) {
         if (table.rows[r].cells[cellNumber].style.display === 'none') {
            continue
         }
      }
      var cellsV = table.rows[r].cells[cellNumber].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
      console.log(cellsV);
      var displayStyle = 'none';
      for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
         if (cellsV.toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i]) >= 0)
            displayStyle = '';
         else {
            displayStyle = 'none';
            break;
         }
      }
      table.rows[r].style.display = displayStyle;
   }
}
```

Comment: После небольшой правки все заработало - спасибо за идею! В конец Вашего примера еще необходимо было добавить присваивание "table.rows[r].cells[1].style.display = displayStyle;", потому как ориентируется фильтр на стиль ячейки, а не строки в целом